# Database Application/Solution

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to develop a database solution that will have 5 or 6 different types of contacts with all details(photo, name, CV, notes, other attachments etc). Users should be able to view and update information. This database has to be searchable with tags using boolean words (such as 'and','or' etc) and should be able to generate results and reports. Once the data is searched and information is retrieved, they should be able to print the information along with attachments. Finally, this application should be accessible everywhere.

The application users are limited to 10-15 people. Number of contacts in the database would be around 3000 for now. So, it's a pretty simple application. Please let me know which database(access,mysql,oracle etc) to use, which technology to use for front end design, where to host it to make it pervasive etc.

Thank you so much for your time. Hope to hearing from you soon.

-Sai

Answer (score 2):

You should use MySQL or some other open source DB. Since the number of records is very minimal and if you don't think it will grow to enterprise grade numbers, then community MySQL should be enough. Then you should consider making your backend accessible through an API created using some web language, like PHP or Python. Once you have your basic authentication and CRUD operations in form of an API, you can then either make a web site (for instance one that is viewable through desktop or mobile) or you can make mobile applications or desktop applications that access this data. Of course this all depends on whether or not your clients will have access to the internet.